# php faceted search

Tags: php, search, full-text-search, faceted-search

i have table **question**(mysql with php) which contains question,category(multiple) and subcat(multiple) its belong. for simplification while saving each question i saved the category in comma separated as below

```
qid    question      catid    subcat
2     question1        2,3,4   5,7
```

like this i have 1000 of question right now in DB

while coming with **faceted search** i want to filter out for each category and its corresponding subcat like tree format below

```
 cat1(5)
   subcat1(3)
   .........
 cat2(24)
 ..........
```

For this i just implemented **in_array** while searching for particular cat for each question in **for each loop** for that question table.The page getting slow now . along with text search also.

is it really good idea or suggest me some right way .

whether i wanna seperate table for category ?

Thanxs,
Gobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the right way to do this is to have separate tables for both category and sub-category as:

```
Table Category
--------------
qid   cat-id


Table Sub_category
------------------
qid   sub_cat_id
```

This way your question table reduces to:

```
Table Question
---------------
id    Question
```

Comment: oh thanxs let see whats other guys suggestion too

Comment: I don't think you'll get many different answers, this is standard Database normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

Right way to store relations information in a separate table. So, may be you'll find this structure useful:

`question` table, contains question info:

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (`id` int, `question` text);
```

Table containing category info:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (`id` int, `parent_id` int, `category` tinytext);
```

table, contains relations:

```
CREATE TABLE `question_category` (`question_id` int, `category_id` int);
```

With this structure you`ll have big categories depth and big relations number easy.